# IntelliJ Run/Debug Configuration - Before launch sequence: Starting with Tomcat Server doesn't progress

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've got a legacy Java web app, for debugging purposed I run it locally on Tomcat. I'm working on integrating a new stack into it, consisting of Spring Boot and Angular. I usually have to do three things: Start the legacy on Tomcat with its own Run/Debug config, start the new stack backend with its own Run/Debug config, start the new stack frontend using grunt via terminal.

To make this a single operation I'm trying to make the Spring Boot backend the starting point. I've set up the Run/Debug Configuration's Before launch process to do the following:

1. Run the legacy on Tomcat
2. Standard build the new stack backend
3. Maven install the new stack backend
4. Run a Grunt task to start the new stack frontend

My problem is when it starts, it doesn't get past starting the Tomcat server. It seems like it's waiting for the legacy Tomcat server to end before going forward. Is there a way to make it continue with the backend build as soon as the Tomcat server is deployed to localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Run configuration Before Launch steps will always wait for the previous task to complete before launching the next one.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7248-multirun might be a better option for this specific use case.